# I am looking for an image viewer library similar to OpenSeaDragon but compatible for C++

Tags: windows, c++, image-viewer

I am working on a windows MFC application, and I would like to rewrite the image viewer using something similar to OpenSeaDragon to utilize it's tile fetching/caching capabilities. I have something like an http endpoint that can fetch the tiles as pngs. The images I'm working with are very large with gaussian pyramids, similar to DeepZoom Images (but not in that format).

Comment: I work for the vendors of LEADTOOLS imaging SDKs. Our C/C++ libraries contain functions for feed-loading large images from buffers (incremental loading) as well as the ability to handle and display large images. If you would like to try these functions, you can download the free evaluation using [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) then contact our support team to discuss the best way to use these functions for your application's purpose. Please note that technical support is free both for evaluation users and registered SDK owners.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using publishlet.com it will convert your images to flipbook, it will allow you to view your flipbook just like viewing a map, It will adjust the resolution and load tiles as you zoom in. This technique will make your flipbook lightweight and responsive. and you can impede the flipbook/viewer in your website or application as an Iframe